# jQuery - using context in chain?

Tags: jquery, dom, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have a page with multiple tables and I want to include the number of rows of each table in a  value. There is an overall table and then other tables that are sub categories. The overall table may remove a row, which would need to update itself and a sub categories post deletion.

Example:

```
Overall table: th 1: Items (50)
Cat 1 table: th 1: Items (20)
Cat 2 table: th 1: Items (30)
```

I'm using jquery and I'm trying to write a function that will just update all tables currently but I'm having a context issue when trying to change the html of the th element.

```
$('table th:nth-child(1)').html("Items (" + $('tbody').children().length + ")");
```

I'm trying to write an 1 line solution instead of a brute force approach of doing id selections for each table.
I'm not sure how to keep the context to just the current table I'm on and not selecting all tbody elements. Is there a way I can use context or the $(this) variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets all `<th>` elements to the same value (using `.text()` is better than using `.html()`):

```
$('table th:nth-child(1)').text("Items (" + $('tbody tr').length + ")");
```

This uses a callback function to calculate a dynamic text value for each `<th>` element:

```
$('table th:nth-child(1)').text(function () {
    var rowCount = $(this).find('tbody tr').length;
    return "Items (" + rowCount + ")";
});
```

Another way to express the same operation is to use `.each()`:

```
$('table').each(function () {
    var rowCount = $(this).find('tbody tr').length
    $(this).find('th:nth-child(1)').text("Items (" + rowCount + ")");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the last solution, makes the most sense to me.

Comment: @jeeden There is always more than one way to do it with jQuery. I tend to use `.each()` most of the time, too - it's most versatile. The 2nd solution is probably a bit faster (academically speaking) since it only does one single CSS search. The net difference, if you have only a handful of tables on your page, is probably zero.